# Add date as string to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am making a script to print some labels and need to import a excell file with ID numbers and DOBs. The DOBs are already formatted correctly in the spreadsheet, but when I import it to a dataframe it converts it to date time and adds a time stamp.

Spreadsheet input

```
IDS     DOB
1       10/21/18
```

then the following code

```
df = pd.read_excel(file,sheetname = "Sheet1",dtype=str )
```

Gives this DataFrame output

```
IDS     DOB
1       2018-10-21 00:00:00
```

Even though I told it to import as a string.

Some rows don't have DOBs or have notes so when I try to use an apply function like

```
df['DOB'] = df['DOB'].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x,'%D%M%Y'))
```

I get

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: -10-10 00:00:00
```

when I try

```
df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'],format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

It still outputs as

```
 2018-10-21 00:00:00
```

Comment: have you tried without the `format` parameter, `df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'])`

Comment: BWT: spreadsheet may keep it as `2018-10-21 00:00:00` and only display as `10/21/18` usings some settings in Excel - and this may gives you `2018-10-21 00:00:00` when you read it even with `dtypes=str` - it simply keep it as is `"2018-10-21 00:00:00"`. You may have to convert string to datetime and later back to string using `"%m/%d/%Y"` or create function which split `"2018-10-21 00:00:00"` by `-` and use values `2018`, `10`, `21` ro create string `10/21/18`. BTW: if there are values which are not correct date then you may need some `try/except` or `if/else`keep them without converting.

Comment: @furas could that be addressed with `parse_dates` from `read_excel`

Comment: I don't have Excel file to test it (I preferre CSV) but if you get it as strings in `DataFrame` then you can do `df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%y')`

Comment: Fixing the excell format worked. I just did a values only paste into a text only cell and it fixed it. Also, exporting to csv works as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have all dates as strings then you could convert to datetime and format it to string again

```
df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
```

---

Minimal working example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'IDS': [1],
    'DOB': ['2018-10-21 00:00:00'],
})
print(df)

df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB']).dt.strftime('%m/%d/%y')
print(df)
```

---

If there are other strings then you may need function which use `try/except` to catch error when you try to convert these values and return original string.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'IDS': [1, 2],
    'DOB': ['2018-10-21 00:00:00', 'Hello World'],
})
print('\n--- before ---\n')
print(df)

def convert(value):
    try: 
        return pd.to_datetime(value).strftime('%m/%d/%y')
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        
    return value
        
df['DOB'] = df['DOB'].apply(convert)
print('\n--- after ---\n')
print(df)
```

Result:

```
--- before ---

   IDS                  DOB
0    1  2018-10-21 00:00:00
1    2          Hello World
('Unknown string format:', 'Hello World')

--- after ---

   IDS          DOB
0    1     10/21/18
1    2  Hello World
```

---

**BTW:** I don't have Excel file for test but maybe if you use this `convert()` with `parse_dates` in `read_excel` then it convert it when you read file.